# Botman Lararavel getContact

Tags: laravel, telegram

```
 public function askEmail()
    {
        return $this->ask('Отправьте контакт?', function (Answer $answer) {
            // Save result
            if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                $this->contacts = $answer->getMessage()->getContact();
                $this->bot = $answer->getMessage()->getConversationIdentifier();
                Log::info($this->contacts);
                Log::info($this->bot);
            }

            $this->text = $answer->getText();

            Log::info($this->contacts);
            Log::info($this->text);
            $this->say('Ваш контакт записан ' . $this->firstname);
        }, [
                'reply_markup' => json_encode([
                    'keyboard' => [[['text' => 'Show phone', 'request_contact' => true,  'remove_keyboard' => true,
                        'resize_keyboard' => true , ]]]
                ])
            ]

        );



    }
```

Бот подключен, сообщения ходят, кнопки и прочие штуки работают. Не могу получить контакты пользователя по кнопке отправить контакты. Пустое сообщение. Подключал через  Ngrok смотрел запросы, запрос есть. В этом куске кода $answer->getMessage()->getContact(); не дает json с ответом. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: BotMan Version: ^2
PHP Version: 7.4
Messaging Service(s): Telegram
Cache Driver: SymfonyCache

Answer (score 0):

Не ответ в прямом смысле, но не приходит отправленный контакт кнопкой. Набранный текст да. Отказался от использования данной библиотеки. Предположения: библиотека всегда обращается к кешу (драйверы пробовал разные), и не может распарсить свой же кеш. Плюс еще и на версию php были ссылки (apcu). Не разбирался, не было времени. Использовал другую библиотеку все закрутилось без вопросов.